# How to manage long title with progressbar

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles

I'm using `progressbar`. I need some help to manage my "too long title". The usual commands  `\title [short title] {long title}` doesn't work. I'm looking for any way to use a short title in the footnotes or to completely erase it from the footnotes. I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so the community can have something to work with?

Comment: Thank you Werner..  I wrote to the builder of progressbar and he gave me the "trick".. The solution is to open the .sty file and make the following replacement : and do the following replacement, in line 72:
\inserttitle -> \insertshorttitle

Comment: the .sty file is    beamerouterthemeprogressbar.sty

Comment: When I use `\title[short title]{long title}`, I get the `short title` in the footer next to the progress bar. [The theme](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/en/LaTeX.php) is dated Oct 4, 2013.

Comment: Thanks Werner! I'm using an older version of progreesbar (0.33) where the short title were not included..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated version of a package that is resolved with an update.